# Animation in swift gets reverted after some actions

Tags: swift, animation

I have to hide a field when user selects an option from a segment input.
The field which hides is first, so I have to animate other fields to cover space created by the field hidden.

I am using following code for that, Animation works as expected after hiding phone input. but when I select any other field from same view (email or any button or anything else) emailInput is again displayed on same place where it was before..Effects of animation (place of input) is lost.

```
@IBAction func hasPhoneChanged(sender: UISegmentedControl) {//is called when user selects that "he have phone or not"
        if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {//Yes
            self.phoneInput.hidden = false
            ...
        }else{                               //No
            self.phoneInput.hidden = true 
            //move the next input up, to cover space    
            UIView.animateWithDuration(1, animations: { () -> Void in
                self.emailInput.frame.origin.y = self.emailInput.frame.origin.y - 38;
            })
        }
    }
```

Am I doing something wrong? Any clue please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using auto layout, animate the auto layout constraints instead.
Example:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(1, animations: { () -> Void in
 self.emailTopVSpaceConstraint.constant = self.emailTopVSpaceConstraint.constant - 38;
 self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
})
```

Comment: You are right, I was using auto layout. And that was the problem. Now it stays on animated position. But now it doesn't animate, it just appears directly on where I want it to appear.. This is what I use now "UIView.animateWithDuration(1, animations: { () -> Void in
                self.emailTopVSpaceConstraint.constant = self.emailTopVSpaceConstraint.constant - 38
            })"

Comment: Call layoutIfNeeded in your animation block to make the calculations for the destination position to happen. Edited my answer.

Comment: Correct answer! For knowledge, what would be more efficient way 1) animate by property (height/width) and in `completion:` set the constraint or 2) animate by constraint as you showed above.

Comment: Make sure to call `layoutIfNeeded` in the *superview* of the view that contains the constraints.

Comment: As far as I know, you should not touch the frame when using auto layout. Look at is as an output variable rather than input.